# JavaScript "compilers"

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction, compression, google-closure-compiler

Recently I found such cool thing as [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). Are there alternatives which provide opportunities to get benefits of compiled statically-typed languages?

***Update***

It is not about real compilers, it is about JavaScript-JavaScript translators, which provide types verification etc, optimization, and maybe compression.

Comment: The so-called Javascript compilers are more like Javascript optimizers. 

The code still needs to be executed by the Javascript engine of the browser, so it still has to be valid JS. Everything they can do is shorten all identifiers and remove whitespaces to reduce the file size and maybe do some minor optimizations on the JS layer, but they can never reach the execution speed of a compiled language.

Comment: @Philipp So you're saying compiled languages' execution speed is faster than JS? I always thought it was the other way around (especially with my computer)...

Comment: What do you mean by 'benefits of compiled statically-typed languages'?  Do you mean you want to write C-style code which **compiles** into JavaScript (like [dart](http://www.dartlang.org/))? As Phillip points out, optimization isn't **compilation**. No matter what you find, you're still running JavaScript.

Comment: Why did Google name their tool with the word compiler? That's a recipe for confusion surely.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I believe it's named that way because it compiles all of the `goog` utilities used within your code into a single sort of framework. In this case, 'compile' is more like 'aggregate'.

Comment: @David - Yes, compiled code runs faster than JS - why wouldn't it? Why do you think it is the other way around on your computer?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think it's specific to my computer because when I want to build and run C++ it takes quite a while to compile (I recently discovered it's because I'm including <iostream>. When I take it out it runs much faster). When I use jsfiddle for javascript it runs noticeably faster.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Sorry I didn't know that. But is execution the same thing as what we call "runtime"?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil "Cannot"? That's a tall claim. Keep in mind that state-of-the-art JavaScript interpreters are able to rewrite the machine code they generate to optimize for commonly used pathways, after observing real-world characteristics. That's something your C++ compiler can't do, and it's 100% believable that there exist corner cases in which it will result in better runtime performance; modern JIT compilation engines can do some damned impressive things that AOT compilers can't.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Parsing only matters for startup time, not for runtime performance. As for "optimizing for commonly used pathways", an AOT compiler has to guess ahead-of-time; it has no way to adjust its behavior if this guess is wrong. A JIT compiler, by contrast, can modify the generated machine code after-the-fact if analyzing the behavior of the code contradicts the initial guess. Mind you, one can have an ahead-of-time compiler compile to bytecode, and a JIT compiler going from bytecode to native instructions -- see all modern JVMs.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil There is overhead, especially at startup -- but a good JIT will eventually optimize for the pathway where something is the expected type, and only go through full introspection when that code path fails.

Comment: The Closure Compiler is called a Compiler because it performs all the functions you would expected from say a C++ compiler (type check, dead code elimination, function and variable inlining, etc) the only difference is rather than generating machine code it generates JavaScript.  JavaC doesn't produce machine code either, it produces Bytecode and JavaC does little beyond type checking and producing Bytecode (it leaves almost all optimizations to the JVM).   In concept, the Closure Compiler is actually closer to an optimizing C++ compiler than the Java compiler.

Answer (score 6):

From your comment:

> I am interested in type checking, interface checking, private fields checking etc, all things allows you to write safety code, not only minimizer.

JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language that does not have built-in support for classes, interfaces, or access modifiers. Closure Compiler supports various extralinguistic features such as interfaces and access modifiers by using information embedded in JSDoc comments. Several IDEs also provide static analysis using JSDoc tag information, for example, see **WebStorm & PhpStorm Blog: [New in 5.0: Google Closure Compiler JSDoc annotations](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/closure-syntax/)**.

In the area of JavaScript minifiers there are numerous options such as [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), [dojo shrinksafe](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/), [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/), and [JSMIN](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html). However, none of these tools provide the same level of support for JSDoc-based analysis as Closure Compiler.

Related stack overflow questions:

1. [Which Javascript minifier (cruncher) does the same things that the one Google uses for its JS APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489847/1164465)
2. [What are some good css and js minimizers for production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/702907/1164465)
3. [Type checker for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929880/1164465)
4. [Is there a good JavaScript minimizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3520285/1164465)
5. [JavaScript and CSS minimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843871/1164465)
6. [JavaScript compression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417635/1164465)
7. [What is the current state of JavaScript static type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6672629/1164465)

Answer (score 2):

Closure compiler (Google) is a true compiler for javascript.  Alternatives include typescript (Microsoft) and Flow (facebook).  Closure compiler uses jsdoc comments to annotate types.  Typescript uses a different syntax than es3/es5 to provide type annotations that compiles to plain javascript.  Flow piggybacks onto the OCaml language (which excels in type inference) to infer as much type information as possible, but can consume annotations in a comment syntax as well.  Closure compiler is also working on better type inference, but it is not ready for production.

In response to @EASI: The closure compiler is a true compiler, not just a minifier.  It works by:

1. Parsing a set of input .js files and a set of extern files (that defined interfaces for ecma 3,5,6 and common browser objects like Window, etc) into an abstract syntax tree (AST).
2. Running a series of compiler passes over the AST to rewrite, transform, eliminate dead code etc.
3. Emit the AST back into js source code.  It will either concatenate the files back together with comments stripped out (WHITESPACE_ONLY), rename and minify symbols within function definitions (SIMPLE), or rename and rewrite all symbols into a minified and obfuscated form (ADVANCED).

Here's a list of compiler passes, for those that are interested.  As you can see, there is a lot going on:

`AliasExternals.java
    AliasStrings.java
    AmbiguateProperties.java
    AnalyzeNameReferences.java
    AnalyzePrototypeProperties.java
    AstValidator.java
    CallGraph.java
    ChainCalls.java
    CheckConformance.java
    CheckDebuggerStatement.java
    CheckEventfulObjectDisposal.java
    CheckGlobalNames.java
    CheckMissingGetCssName.java
    CheckRegExp.java
    CheckSideEffects.java
    ClosureCodeRemoval.java
    ClosureOptimizePrimitives.java
    CollapseAnonymousFunctions.java
    CollapseProperties.java
    CollapseVariableDeclarations.java
    ConstCheck.java
    ConstParamCheck.java
    ConvertDeclaredTypesToJSDoc.java
    ConvertToDottedProperties.java
    ConvertToTypedES6.java
    CoverageInstrumentationPass.java
    CreateSyntheticBlocks.java
    CrossModuleCodeMotion.java
    CrossModuleMethodMotion.java
    DeclaredGlobalExternsOnWindow.java
    DefaultPassConfig.java
    Denormalize.java
    DisambiguateProperties.java
    ErrorPass.java
    Es6ToEs3ClassSideInheritance.java
    ExpandJqueryAliases.java
    ExportTestFunctions.java
    ExternExportsPass.java
    ExtractPrototypeMemberDeclarations.java
    FlowSensitiveInlineVariables.java
    FunctionNames.java
    FunctionRewriter.java
    GatherExternProperties.java
    GatherRawExports.java
    GenerateExports.java
    GlobalNamespace.java
    GlobalTypeInfo.java
    GroupVariableDeclarations.java
    ImplicitNullabilityCheck.java
    InferConsts.java
    InjectEs6RuntimeLibrary.java
    InlineFunctions.java
    InlineObjectLiterals.java
    InlineProperties.java
    InlineVariables.java
    InstrumentFunctions.java
    JsMessageVisitor.java
    MarkNoSideEffectCalls.java
    MethodCompilerPass.java
    MinimizeExitPoints.java
    NameAnalyzer.java
    NameAnonymousFunctions.java
    NameAnonymousFunctionsMapped.java
    NameReferenceGraphConstruction.java
    NewTypeInference.java
    Normalize.java
    ObjectPropertyStringPostprocess.java
    ObjectPropertyStringPreprocess.java
    OptimizeArgumentsArray.java
    OptimizeCalls.java
    OptimizeParameters.java
    PeepholeOptimizationsPass.java
    PhaseOptimizer.java
    PrepareAst.java
    ProcessCommonJSModules.java
    ProcessDefines.java
    ProcessTweaks.java
    PureFunctionIdentifier.java
    RecordFunctionInformation.java
    RemoveUnusedClassProperties.java
    RemoveUnusedNames.java
    RemoveUnusedPrototypeProperties.java
    RemoveUnusedVars.java
    RenameLabels.java
    RenameProperties.java
    RenamePrototypes.java
    RenameVars.java
    ReplaceCssNames.java
    ReplaceIdGenerators.java
    ReplaceStrings.java
    RescopeGlobalSymbols.java
    RuntimeTypeCheck.java
    SanityCheck.java
    ShadowVariables.java
    SideEffectsAnalysis.java
    SimpleDefinitionFinder.java
    StrictModeCheck.java
    StripCode.java
    SymbolTable.java
    TransformAMDToCJSModule.java
    TypeInferencePass.java
    TypedScopeCreator.java
    UnreachableCodeElimination.java
    VariableVisibilityAnalysis.java`

Comment: I may be splitting hairs (as the saying goes), but I think the 3rd item you listed pretty much nullifies your argument. A compiler generally takes a human readable language and converts it into machine code. When the Closure "Compiler" converts all of its work back into JavaScript, isn't that new code just going to be run on an ordinary JavaScript engine?

I'm not saying that what the Closure "Compiler" is doing isn't extensive and very close to the same thing that a regular compiler does, but in the end it's just restructuring JavaScript, not 'compiling' it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There are Java, JS, PHP, CSS, and HTML "**minifiers**".
For example, when you use Google GWT Java for programming, the code is generated as a minimization of JS.

---

They use the term compiler, but it is not correct. Compilers turn one human readable language code into a object code that only interpreters or machines can read. What this google tool does is to optimize your code so it can be read faster by the interpreter. Script languages needs interpreters to be executed. Programs compiled into machine language are executed faster than any interpreter could. But of course that any program speed depends on it's execution flow project and the experience of the developing team.

---

**New:**

Have you tryed to make your JavaScript codes in a specialized IDE?
If you're looking for type cheking, you could try one of these:

- NuSphere PhpED Professional v7 (best)
- phpDesigner 8
- Aptana Studio
- Zend Studio
- DreamWeaver CS6

They have a greater support now, not only for PHP, but for JavaScript, with Code Auto-Complete, Type Verification, Dynamic Syntax Highlighting, Multiple Language Syntax Highlighting and Oriented Object Analysis and Auto Complete as you type.

Comment: The Closure Compiler acts as a "minimizer" in basic mode, but in advanced mode it really _does_ act very much like a genuine compiler, but which happens to have JavaScript, rather than bytecode or machine code as its target language. There's not just a peephole optimizer but codepath/reachability analysis, function inlining, and all the other things you expect a good optimizing compiler to do.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil, Try http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, GCC is the state of the art programming. It's like some robot reading your software and then rebuild it 5x better. It's how google makes it's Gmail a great Web 2.0 service.

Comment: +1. GWT is an excellent example of having a static language compile into js.

Comment: Sorry, @CharlesDuffy. It was really pointed to you.

Comment: @EASI Then we're in violent agreement -- which is to say: we're saying the same thing; I don't understand why you would feel a need to contradict.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil, I have edited my answer to include some software that helps you in the type verification, interface checking (aptana) etc.

Comment: @EASI The Closure Compiler has type verification, interface checking, and the like on its own in advanced mode, if one is using appropriate annotations. You might consider some links on that topic as well.

Comment: Sorry that I did not. I will put the official site of each because there they explain all about it.

Comment: People, please don't call Google Closure Compiler "GCC". Unix has its own GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) which might cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [furiascript.com](http://furiascript.com) can be the interesting option.