# Checking the types of function arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is there any way to check the types of a function's arguments? I want to write a function called `checkTypes` that does the following:

```
function checkTypes(typeArr){
    //if the types do not match typeArr, throw an error
}

function exampleUsage(arr1, arr2, num1){
    checkTypes("object", "object", "number");
    //throw an error if the types do not match the corresponding elements
}
```

Comment: In order to get this to work properly, I'll need to find a way to get the array of arguments from inside a function.

Comment: You can access an arguments object with all the arguments and the number of arguments.  It behaves much like an array (though it isn't one).  Read this for more info:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: the question you should be asking yourself is, why do you care what type the arguments are?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm trying to mimic static typing in Javascript, which is supported in many other languages.

Comment: You wouldn't try to write English as though it were Japanese, why would you try to write JavaScript as if it were some other language?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Stop it.  :P  Javascript is not any of those many other languages.  The whole concept of *classes* doesn't even exist natively; it's bolted on to appease people who can't wrap their heads around prototypes, and is so easy to subvert (even accidentally!) that relying on it for much of anything will drive you insane.

Comment: @cHao Is there any reason why I should avoid type-checking the input of a function in JavaScript? I think it would be very useful in some cases (i. e., to ensure that all the parameters of the function `getCommonFactors()` are integers, or that all parameters of the function `haveSameLength(arr1, arr2)` are arrays).

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Because *you don't care whether they're all integers*.  If you do, you simply don't call it with anything else.  (Keep in mind, too, JS doesn't even *have* "integers" -- it just has "numbers".)  As for why it's bad, consider that `3` and `new Number(3)` are equivalent in all respects but two: (1) they don't compare as equal with `===`, and (2) the latter is an `object`.  If you just treat a Number as a number, all's good.  If you absolutely need a primitive, use `+` to convert it.  If you care about type, though, suddenly those two differences become very significant.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: You can't reliably check whether `arr1` is an array.  Arrays are objects, and thus fall into the non-type-system.  You could check prototypes or constructors or whatever, but that's all pretty easily subverted, even by accident.  The best you can do is check whether it has the properties and methods you need it to have.  And at that point, you've moved from strict typing to duck typing.

Comment: @cHao How can the checking of prototypes or constructors be subverted?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: `myArray.constructor = Object;`, for example.  Or `Array = function() {};`.  Depends on how you do your type check, but basically, no one way of checking is foolproof.  You'd have to verify stuff a half dozen different ways, at which point you've spent more time on bureaucracy than actual work.

Comment: @cHao: `Object.prototype.toString.call(value) == '[object Array]'` is a sound check. You seem to be suggesting that determining the nature of a value is a hopeless pursuit. It is not.

Comment: @davidchambers: Congrats.  You've just basically outlawed inheritance.

Comment: @davidchambers: And what i'm mostly saying is, *it's not worth the trouble*.  Static typing brings two major benefits: (1) it can catch certain kinds of errors early, and (2) it can improve performance.  Both are possible because it happens at *compile time*.  Run-time static typing is basically B&D.  It's "i wish JS were Java".

Comment: > I wish `JS` were `Java` > `Dart` has entered the chat

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the the `typeOf` function adapted from this post [Fixing the JavaScript typeof operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/) combined with this function:

```
function typeOf( obj ) {
  return ({}).toString.call( obj ).match(/\s(\w+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

function checkTypes( args, types ) {
  args = [].slice.call( args );
  for ( var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i ) {
    if ( typeOf( args[i] ) != types[i] ) {
      throw new TypeError( 'param '+ i +' must be of type '+ types[i] );
    }
  }
}

function foo( a,b,c ) {
  checkTypes( arguments, ['string', 'number', 'array'] );
  return 'foo';
}

console.log( foo( 'a', 1, [2] ) ); //=> foo
console.log( foo( 1, 1, [2] ) ); 
//^ Uncaught TypeError: param 0 must be of type string
```

Comment: Is there any way to obtain the arguments of the calling function in checkTypes (without passing in the arguments as a parameter)?

Comment: There must be a way but why you want to do this? You could use TypeScript for example if you need strong typing.

Comment: Here's a modified version of the code above (with the same output, but slightly more concise): http://jsfiddle.net/BpVBG/

Comment: You should throw a `TypeError` here, not a string.

Comment: Doesn't `{}.toString` (or any property) give a syntax error?

Comment: @chharvey you're right. it should be `({}).toString`

Answer (score 10):

Do not use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) in this case. It's problematic for several reasons:

```
typeof null                 // 'object'
typeof []                   // 'object'
typeof 'foo'                // 'string'
typeof new String('foo')    // 'object'
'foo' == new String('foo')  // true
```

Instead, use `Object::toString`:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(null)               // '[object Null]'
Object.prototype.toString.call([])                 // '[object Array]'
Object.prototype.toString.call('foo')              // '[object String]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(new String('foo'))  // '[object String]'
```

A decorator would meet your requirements:

```
var getType = function(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value)
    .replace(/^\[object |\]$/g, '').toLowerCase();
};

var checkTypes = function(types, fn) {
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    for (var idx = 0; idx < types.length; idx += 1) {
      var expected = types[idx];
      var received = getType(args[idx]);
      if (received != expected) {
        throw new TypeError('expected ' + expected + '; received ' + received);
      }
    }
    fn.apply(null, args);
  };
};

var exampleUsage = checkTypes(['array', 'array', 'number'], function(arr1, arr2, num1) {
  console.log('arr1:', arr1);
  console.log('arr2:', arr2);
  console.log('num1:', num1);
});
```

Usage examples:

```
exampleUsage([], [], 0);
// arr1: []
// arr2: []
// num1: 0

exampleUsage([], [], 'foo');
// TypeError: expected number; received string
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a modified version of `typeof` and the `arguments` pseudo-array to get each argument type and compare it to your desired set of types:

```
// from Doug Crockford http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html
function typeOf(value) {
    var s = typeof value;
    if (s === 'object') {
        if (value) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) == '[object Array]') {
                s = 'array';
            }
        } else {
            s = 'null';
        }
    }
    return s;
}

function checkTypes(argList, typeList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < typeList.length; i++) {
        if (typeOf(argList[i]) !== typeList[i]) {
            throw 'wrong type: expecting ' + typeList[i] + ", found " + typeOf(argList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ywyLe/

---

Example Usage:

```
function exampleUsage(arr1, arr2, num1){
    //throw an error if the types do not match the corresponding elements
    checkTypes(arguments, ["array", "array", "number"]);
}
```

Comment: In checkTypes, is it possible to obtain the args list from the calling function, without explicitly passing it as a parameter? It would be more concise this way, if it were possible.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Obtaining arguments of a calling function is not possible in a cross-browser fashion.  You get the arguments of the current function - that's all.

Comment: I've made a couple of modifications to your script to handle JavaScript's optional parameters. http://jsfiddle.net/LS6YJ/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.

Comment: Yes, I could use the `typeof` operator to implement the `exampleUsage` function. But how can I obtain the arguments of a function from inside the function?

Comment: This doesn't answer the entire question, but it's a good start, at least. :)

Comment: Oh okay, if you need arguments then you can see [built-in arguments array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). (Also mentioned by @Surreal in comments to your question).

Answer (score 0):

The typeof function return object for most of the thing,

```
alert(typeof("this is string")); /* string */
alert(typeof(1234)); /* number */
alert(typeof([])); /* object */
alert(typeof({})); /* object */
alert(typeof(new Date)); /* object */
alert(typeof(function(){})); /* function */
```

but jQuery can identify by this function jQuery.type( obj )
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

Comment: How does `jQuery.type` differ from the `typeof` operator, specifically?

Comment: For example native typeof function typeof(new Date) will return "object" but jQuery.type(new Date()) will return "date".

Comment: jQuery.type({}) this will return "object" (assosiative array) but jQuery.type([])​ this will return "array" while native javascript typeof will return object in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for require-like environment solution, I can recommend [typeof-arguments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeof-arguments) package.

```
const checkTypes = require('typeof-arguments');

function exampleUsage(arr1, arr2, num1){
  checkTypes(arguments,["object", "object", "number"]);
  //throw an error if the types do not match the corresponding elements
}
```

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript is bad for types.
Also, you can not magically access the parent's function arguments from a calling function.

If you don't want to have a big headache, use some simple library to check types.

For example, using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you could write something like this:

```
function exampleUsage(arr1, arr2, num1) {
  if(!_.isArray(arr1) || !_.isArray(arr2) || !_.isNumber(num1) {
    throw "Wrong types"
  }
  // do other stuff
}
```

You are probably afraid of types because you are probably new to dynamic languages. You will see that is not as bad as it looks like, but JavaScrip IS BAD (for a lot other reasons)

Comment: The OP is looking for a general purpose (aka reusable) function to check types, not general comments about the quality of a programming language.

Comment: Why is Javascript "bad for types"? It's possible to check the type of a function using the `typeof` operator. Also, it's possible to obtain the arguments of a function using `arguments`.

Comment: Specifically, why do you think Javascript is "bad"?