# Determine a function object's parameter types

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to determine a function objects parameters so that I can determine their respective types.

```
Params.prototype.getParams = function (fn) {
   var a = fn.length;
   console.log("Args: " + a);

   for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      // This is where I want to print the type
      console.log("Arg[" + i + "] type is: " + typeof(fn.arguments[i]));
   }
}
```

Then if I define a few functions (could be any JS functions), such as:

```
function callback1("one") {}
function callback2("one", 2) {}
function callback3(1, "two", []) {}
```

If I later invoke each:

```
var params = new Params();

params.getParams(callback1);
params.getParams(callback2);
params.getParams(callback3);
```

I would like to figure out each param type for each function instance.  I've Google'd it, searched it on SO but can't find anything helpful.  If it knows the 'length' I don't see why it wouldn't know the params also?

**Update - 2013.02.19 17:41**

Yes, I do know there are potential errors in the code above, I stripped it for simplicity of reading.

Here is what I was trying to accomplish:

I was reading this (interesting) article:  [JavaScript Function Overloading](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/)

Coming from Java and being a purist, I wanted to start experiment with method overloading (damn I can't believe how primitive JS is).

I wanted to 'enhance' the example in the article by replacing the 'function count' methodology with one where the parameter types are used instead to 'resolve' which overloaded function should be invoked.  It seems this is pretty much only doable by actually knowing the parameter types of 'fn' in my example.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926213/checking-the-types-of-function-arguments-in-javascript/13926334#13926334

Comment: Function parameters don't have types. The `.length` of a function describes how many parameters were defined for that function, but that's it. The types will be determined on invocation of the function. You'll need to do your own type checking in the function if desired.

Comment: ...and your function definitions are invalid.

Comment: Function arguments have to be identifiers. You can't have a value as the parameter to a function. `function callback1("one") {}` results in a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Please show an example of how you would use this. What would getParams actually do? There is no way to determine the type of a function parameter because in JS function parameters have names, but can be of any type

Comment: ...or use http://TypeScriptLang.org to get compile-time type checking.

Comment: If you think about a valid function definition `function fun(a,b,c){...}`, you can tell there is no type in a function definition, only names of parameters

Comment: @elclanrs: No, this isn't the same thing.  In the link you provided, he basically 'type compares' arguments, while I'm trying to determine the parameter types of a function object that is passed as argument.

Comment: @JuanMendes: I've updated the question with a description of what I was aiming to resolve.

Comment: @Jeach: You'd probably need to pass to the `addMethod` an Array of types that map to each defined function parameter. Then upon invocation of the wrapper function, analyse the `arguments` object and compare the types from the Array.

Comment: There we go again... perfectly valid and important question but some little kiddy individual down-votes it without explanation... whish we could see who these anonymous cowards are who down votes just because they don't have anything useful to contribute!

Comment: @Jeach I must admit that your question was not very well asked, it has syntax errors and didn't list what you were actually trying to do. It wasn't my downvote, but it wasn't completely unwarranted. Now that I know what you were trying to do, I've posted an answer that should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @Jeach Chrome tells me that your website is loading malware, WTH?

Comment: @thesystem: Yes, passing the types as an array is probably what I'll do and it would resolve my problem... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JuanMendes: Which web site? The one linked in my profile?  If so, that's no web site!  All it has is a single page which I created about 5 years ago to show some people how to use Google ads.  I only use the hosting service for everything else (FTP, emails, etc).  But I do have some company harassing me once a month telling me that I 'must' fix my web site... funny I never created one.  It's ironic that Chrome would complain against it's own scripts if that's the page causing the issue.  If my web provided got hacked and someone added pages, that's another issue. When I get time, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters don't have types, if you want something that is kind of like overloading, you need to implement it yourself.

The simplest way to use it is to overload a getter, and setter method like jQuery does for its `val()` and many other functions. If you don't pass anything, it retrieves the value,  if you pass something, it will set a value. I've written something slightly different than what John Resig suggested. This way, you'll have two examples to look at.

The important thing is that you cannot retrieve the types of parameters, only how many parameters were declared in the function definition.

```
function overload(/*fun1, fun2, fun3... */) {
    var overloadedFuns = arguments;
    return function() {
        var argCount = arguments.length;
        for (var i=0; i < overloadedFuns.length; i++) {
           if (overloadedFuns[i].length === argCount) {
               return overloadedFuns[i].apply(this, arguments);
               break;
           }
        }
    }
}


var obj = {
  _val = 0;
  val: overload(
      // This will get called when called with no arguments
      function() {
          return this._val;
      },
      // This will get called when called with one arguments
      function(val){
          this._val = val;
      }
  )
}

console.log( obj.val() ); // Outputs 0
obj.val(5); // Sets it to 5
console.log( obj.val() ); // Outputs 5
```

A similar concept could be introduced adding types. But since you can't infer the types from the function definition, you'd need to add that information yourself

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UPuwE/1/

```
/**
 * @param {object[]} fnDefs, Each object should contain a paramList and a fn
 *  {paramMap: ["string"], fn: function() {myString}}
 *
 */
function overload(fnDefs) {

    function matches(arr1, arr2) {
        if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return function() {
        var types = [];
        for (var i =0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            types.push(typeof arguments[i]);
        }
        for (var i=0; i < fnDefs.length; i++) {
            if (matches(types, fnDefs[i].paramMap)) {
                return fnDefs[i].fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}


var obj = {
    _val: 0,
    val: overload([
        {
            paramMap: ['string'],
            fn: function(str) {
                this._val = str;
            }
        },

        {
            paramMap: ['object'],
            // If an object is passed in, grab the string from its 
            // str property or by calling the toString() method;
            fn: function(obj) {
                this._val = obj.str || obj.toString();
            }
        },
        {
            paramMap: [],
            // Getter
            fn: function(obj) {
                return this._val;
            }
        }
    ])
};

obj.val('34');
console.log( obj.val() );

obj.val({str: '35'});
console.log( obj.val() );

obj.val( {toString: function(){return '36';} } );
console.log( obj.val() );
```

I hope this example shows you that there's a lot of overhead at runtime, that's why most libraries don't use it

Comment: Thanks for the sample code!  Both you and '@thesystem' have been helpful and provided alternatives that I'll try at a later time.  I'll report my results (successful or not) in an answer to this question.  At that time, I'll select your answer as the 'accepted' answer (unless of course someone comes and provides some miraculous solution in the meantime... but I doubt that).  Again thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 4):

#### Function parameters do not have types.

```
function fun(a,b,c) {... }
```

In JavaScript any variable or function parameter may contain an object or primitive of any type.

The only way to do it is to check at runtime using `arguments`

```
function callback3(a,b,c) {
    if (typeof a != 'string') {
      throw new Error('callback3 expects a string for its first argument');
    }
}
```

Since it looks like you want to type checking, you could abstract this with something like

```
function checkParams(args, types) {
    if (args.length != types.length) {
        throw new Error('Invalid number of arguments passed');
    }
    for (var i=0; i < args.length; i ++) {
        if (typeof args[i] != types[i]) {
            throw new Error('Argument number '+ i +' has wrong type'); 
        }
    }
}

function callback3(a,b,c) {
    checkParams(arguments, ['string', 'number', 'object') );
    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: May be worth explaining that it can be done done inside a function, that's the only way to determine the type of passed in arguments (not declared parameters)

Comment: He used "parameters" when he meant "arguments". I don't feel this answer actually answers the question.

Comment: He is able to get the types of the arguments, as he is looking for.

Comment: @NicholasPickering The OP is clearly trying to determine the type of parameters (not actual arguments), that is evidenced by the fact that they are using `fn.length`. This answer explains it can't be done. I do agree that it would make sense to explain what can be done instead (using `arguments` from within the function)

Comment: Your answer is kind of misleading!  First you say that parameter don't have types?  But if I do 'typeof(arguments[#])' it will give me a type (ie: 'number', 'function', 'array', 'object', 'string', etc), no?  Also, people have voted it up, but yet is clearly way off of what I'm looking for... have you actually taken the time to look at the code example?

Comment: @Jeach: *parameter != argument* ... and this answer is way off from what you were looking for because you failed to adequately describe what you wanted until your recent update.

Comment: @thesystem: Thanks for the clarification.  If 'parameter != argument' in JS then that's something new to me (I thought they were interchangeable)... I will update my question to clarify things once I know the difference.  Depending on language, these are changed interchangeably.

Comment: @Jeach: it boils down to this - JavaScript functions may be called with any number of arguments of any type.  Period.  There is no way to programmatically determine what type of arguments an arbitrary function expects, hence, each and every function must do its own argument checking.

Comment: @Jeach: I see. Yes within JavaScript the word *parameter* will refer to a member of the Formal Parameter list of a function. In other words, it's the identifier you gave that will receive the argument. The argument is the actual value passed.

Comment: I've been looking at your code for the last little while (which is very similar to the link provided by '@elclanrs').  If my overloading attempt proves to have too much bloat, I may refine my code to use the 'checkParams(...)' one liner.  It would clean up my massive 'if-else' logic to type-check inside each function.  It would be a little more verbose and reduce LOC.  So you can say this will be 'Plan B' to clean up my JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `arguments` variable?

```
function sayHi(name) {console.log(arguments)}

    sayHi('hackNightly')
>>> ['hackNightly']
```

It seems like if you had the arguments, you could just loop over them and use typeOf() or something similar to do type checking.

Comment: No, I know about the arguments variable.  In this case it's different because I would need the arguments variable on the function object, if one was available.

Answer (score 0):

The function object no longer stores its arguments, they are available directly inside the function call by using the var `arguments`.

http://www.sitepoint.com/arguments-a-javascript-oddity/

```
  //try this instead
  console.log("Arg[" + i + "] type is: " + typeof(arguments[i]));
```

Comment: The OP's code is not running inside of the function, `arguments` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had an hour to spare, so I figured I would give it a try at implementing various suggestions I received from both 'Juan Mendes' and 'the system'.

The following is just a working example (not optimized, not benchmarked, not cleaned up), so consider it work in progress.  Before I do anything else, I will want to run a few benchmarks to see what kind of 'bloat' it will end up providing.

If anyone sees anything wrong with this, please provide constructive criticism!

```
function Overload() {
    // Empty for now!
}

Overload.prototype.link = function (object, method) {   
    console.log("Creating dispatch method '" + method + "()'");

    object.prototype[method] = function () {
        var target = method + "_";

        console.log("Invoked dispatch method '" + method + "()'...");

        for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            target += (typeof arguments[i]).substring(0, 1);
        }

        console.log("Resolved target as '" + target + "'");

        if (typeof object.prototype._overloaded[target] !== "undefined") {
            console.log("Dispatching to overloaded method: '" + target + "'");
            return object.prototype._overloaded[target].apply(object, arguments);
        } else {
            console.log("Method not found: '" + method + "('" + target + "')'");
            //throw "Exception ...";
        }
    }
}
```

The following function will be used to overload all our other function on the object:

```
Overload.prototype.overload = function (object, method, fn, params) {
    var target = method + "_" + params;

    console.log("Overloading method '" + method + "()' to '" + method + "('" + params + "')'");

    if (typeof object === "undefined") {
        console.log("Object doesn't exist!");
    }

    if (typeof object.prototype[method] === "undefined") {
        this.link(object, method);
    }

    if (typeof object.prototype._overloaded === "undefined") {
        console.log("Creating '[obj].prototype._overloaded' property");
        object.prototype._overloaded = {};
    }

    if (typeof object.prototype._overloaded[target] === "undefined") {
        //console.log("Assigning overload function as target '" + method + "('" + params + "')'");
        object.prototype._overloaded[target] = fn;
    } else {
        console.log("Definition for '" + method + "('" + params + "')' already eixsts!");
    }

    return fn;
}
```

Now define a few sample functions which essentially 'mock' an overloaded function:

```
function fn1(one) {
    console.log("Invoked function 1: " + one);
}

function fn2(one, two) {
    console.log("Invoked function 2: " + one + ", " + two);
}

function fn3(one, two, three) {
    console.log("Invoked function 3: " + one + ", " + two + ", " + three);
}

function fn4(one, two, three) {
    console.log("Invoked function 4: " + one + ", " + two);
}

function fn5(one, two, three) {
    console.log("Invoked function 5: " + one + ", " + two);
}
```

Use this to run our tests:

```
function testMethodOverloading() {
    console.log("Testing method overloading!");

    var ov = new Overload();

    function OBJ() {}

    console.log("--");

    ov.overload(OBJ, "name", fn1, 's');
    ov.overload(OBJ, "name", fn2, 'sn');
    ov.overload(OBJ, "name", fn3, 'sns');
    ov.overload(OBJ, "name", fn4, 'ss');
    ov.overload(OBJ, "name", fn5, 'nn');

    console.log("--");

    var obj = new OBJ();

    obj.name("one");
    obj.name("two", 1);
    obj.name("three", 2, "four");
    obj.name("five", "six");
    obj.name(3, 4);
}
```

This is the output I get from running the test above:

```
Overloading method 'name()' to 'name('s')'
Creating dispatch method 'name()'
Creating '[obj].prototype._overloaded' property
Overloading method 'name()' to 'name('sn')'
Overloading method 'name()' to 'name('sns')'
Overloading method 'name()' to 'name('ss')'
Overloading method 'name()' to 'name('nn')'
--
Invoked dispatch method 'name()'...
Resolved target as 'name_s'
Dispatching to overloaded method: 'name_s'
Invoked function 1: one
Invoked dispatch method 'name()'...
Resolved target as 'name_sn'
Dispatching to overloaded method: 'name_sn'
Invoked function 2: two, 1
Invoked dispatch method 'name()'...
Resolved target as 'name_sns'
Dispatching to overloaded method: 'name_sns'
Invoked function 3: three, 2, four
Invoked dispatch method 'name()'...
Resolved target as 'name_ss'
Dispatching to overloaded method: 'name_ss'
Invoked function 4: five, six
Invoked dispatch method 'name()'...
Resolved target as 'name_nn'
Dispatching to overloaded method: 'name_nn'
Invoked function 5: 3, 4
```

So it definitely runs as I expected/wanted it to!  But what kind of benchmarks will it get.  I'll be doing that next to see if I'm anywhere within the range of the referenced article's benchmarks (after stripping out all the logging, that is).  Once I have a general idea, I'll post the results.